# ParseTraverser crashes on a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, concurrency, parse-android-sdk

So we're running into this really weird, seemingly random crash in the Parse SDK for Android. Normally we would attribute this to maybe a bug in the Parse platform, but it's happening pretty consistently to all our users, and researching the issue doesn't bring up any known causes. In fact, there is only one issue that mildly related to this one, which can be found here; [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029398/getting-concurrentmodificationexception-adding-to-array).

The basic breakdown is that we are detecting the following crash in our Crashlytics logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:787)
       at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:814)
       at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:960)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.visit(ParseTraverser.java:100)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.visit(ParseTraverser.java:94)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.visit(ParseTraverser.java:101)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.visit(ParseTraverser.java:94)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.visit(ParseTraverser.java:101)
       at com.parse.ParseTraverser.traverse(ParseTraverser.java:137)
       at com.parse.OfflineStore.saveLocallyAsync(OfflineStore.java:776)
       at com.parse.OfflineStore.access$200(OfflineStore.java:36)
       at com.parse.OfflineStore$38.then(OfflineStore.java:1251)
       at com.parse.OfflineStore$38.then(OfflineStore.java:1227)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
       at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
       at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
       at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
       at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:32)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:708)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:705)
       at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:956)
       at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:994)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:934)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
       at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:32)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:708)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:705)
       at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:956)
       at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:994)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:934)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
       at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:32)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:708)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:705)
       at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:956)
       at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:994)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:934)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
       at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:32)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:708)
       at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:705)
       at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:956)
       at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:994)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
       at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:934)
       at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:921)
       at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
       at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
       at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
       at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
       at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Now as you can see this stacktrace doesn't show us where the issue is occurring in our code, and we are not able to reproduce it consistently. It appears to pop up randomly, opposed to the previous issue I linked.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? If so, what is causing this? I've checked if our code somewhere loops trough a list of `ParseObject`s and removes entries, but I can't find any instances of this happening.

Comment: Could you provide the source code of com.parse.ParseTraverser.java class?

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala That's part of the Parse platform.

Comment: Where did you provide the source code? You have provided only exception stacktrace.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala I can't provide the source code because, like I explained in the question, don't know where this exception is thrown in my application. Crashlytics doesn't report the actual point in my application that this occurs because it's too deep into a stacktrace. Is there a way to figure out where the original point was trough Crashlytics?

Comment: In the above stacktrace, do you see any classes of your application?

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala Nope. They all come from either the Parse platform, or a library called Bolts. The Parse platform uses Bolts.